# Problem with where clause and count transactions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count how many transactions I have by Currency. When I count without a where clause I get 0 transactions where I have NULL values but when I use a where clause with an IN operator I get a filtered result and no zero results. How to show 0 in count transactions?

```
SELECT 
 c.ShortName, 
 count(ad.AccountId) as No_of_transactions
FROM Currency c
LEFT JOIN Account a ON c.id = a.CurrencyId
LEFT JOIN AccountDetails ad ON a.id = ad.AccountId
LEFT JOIN [Location] l ON ad.LocationId = l.Id
LEFT JOIN LocationType lt ON l.LocationTypeId = lt.Id
WHERE lt.Name IN('Region Branch', 'City Branch')
GROUP BY c.ShortName
```

This is the result that I want to get:

```
EUR 31, 
USD 0, 
GBR 0
```

Comment: I would suggest that you set up a db<>fiddle of some sort . . . or at least provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You **really** need to provide sample data - there are a few articles on how to ask database/SQL questions [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%c3%a9race?tab=profile) - you might want to take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  c.ShortName,
  COUNT(t.Id) as No_of_transations
FROM Currency c
LEFT JOIN Account a ON c.id = a.CurrencyId
LEFT JOIN AccountDetails ad ON a.id = ad.AccountId
LEFT JOIN [Location] l ON ad.LocationId = l.Id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM LocationType lt WHERE lt.Name IN('Region Branch', 'City 
Branch')) AS t ON l.LocationTypeId = t.Id 
GROUP BY c.ShortName
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `LEFT JOIN`.  The filtering needs to go in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT c.ShortName, 
       COUNT(lt.id) as No_of_transactions
FROM Currency c LEFT JOIN
     Account a
     ON c.id = a.CurrencyId LEFT JOIN
     AccountDetails ad
     ON a.id = ad.AccountId  LEFT JOIN
     [Location] l
     ON ad.LocationId = l.Id  LEFT JOIN
     LocationType lt
     ON l.LocationTypeId = lt.Id AND
        lt.Name IN ('Region Branch', 'City Branch')
GROUP BY c.ShortName;
```

In your version, the non-matches turn into `NULL`s, which the `WHERE` conditions filter out.

Comment: But now i do not have filter by branches. Code is functioning like without where clause: USD 0, BGN 0, RSD 0, MKD 2520, EUR 226, HRK 0. I want this result USD 0, BGN 0, RSD 0, MKD 331, EUR 31, HRK 0

Comment: @Gjurcin . . . I think you want to count `lt.id` -- the last in the chain of `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: I want to count transactions by currency but some currency do not have transactions. So that the problem when i count without where is correct i can show 0 transactions. But when i use where clause NULL is not counted as 0 like before

Answer (score 0):

You want to move the condition on the `left join`ed table from the `where` clause to the `on` clause of the relevant join to avoid records being filtered out when they do not exist in that table.

Also, I think that you need `COUNT(DISTINCT ad.id)` (as per the comments, a transaction is uniquely represented by this column):

```
SELECT 
    c.ShortName, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ad.id) as No_of_transactions
FROM Currency c
LEFT JOIN Account a ON c.id = a.CurrencyId
LEFT JOIN AccountDetails ad ON a.id = ad.AccountId
LEFT JOIN [Location] l ON ad.LocationId = l.Id
LEFT JOIN LocationType lt ON l.LocationTypeId = lt.Id AND lt.Name IN('Region Branch', 'City Branch')
GROUP BY c.ShortName
```

Comment: this is almost correct one, but in one currency i missing one record. Why is that so?

Comment: @Gjurcin: since we are doing only `left join`s, all currencies that can be found in table `Currency` will show in this result. You might need to double check your output.

Comment: there are id's which made two transactions with distinct we remove them and we missed if someone made more than one transaction. We should find other solution

Comment: @Gjurcin: what column represents a transaction in your tables?

Comment: [dbo].[AccountDetails]
id, AccountId, LocationId, EmployeeId, TransactionDate, Amount, PurposeCode, PurposeDescription

Comment: @Gjurcin: ok so you need `COUNT(DISTINCT ad.id)`. I updated the query.

Comment: again i get the same result as before like no filter in query